# Separating NSFetchedResultsController sections into arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a NSFetchedResultsController that seperates my results into two sections. What I simply want to do is separate each section into its own array. Something like this, but this sends me an unrecognized selector error:

```
array1=[[[theFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0] allObjects];
array2=[[[theFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:1] allObjects];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because instances of `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` don't respond to `-allObjects`. They respond to `-objects`.

`allObjects` is an instance method of `NSSet`.